# Gradle transitive dependency Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

so I have a multi-modular android project that will finally produce an aar,
in the android project I have

- Project A
- Project B
- Project C

Project B has api (Project A) and project C has api(Project B) and the aar will be produced from project C.

when building an AAR from Project C, it does not include project B or A when importing aar to other project

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://proandroiddev.com/better-dependencies-management-using-buildsrc-kotlin-dsl-eda31cdb81bf) is the dependency management tutorial on the central dependency system in the Android project.